# Export Chart to Excel File

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, charts, export

I am new in `C# Programming`. I am creating a `winform application` in which I am using `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization Chart`. This `chart` contains multiple series. I want to export that chart data to Excel file.

To Add Data to chart I am using

```
 chart.Series[mSeries].Points.AddXY(dt, avgData);
```

dt is `current DateTime` and the `data`.

So my Excel file look like

First Column is `Series Name`, second is `DateTime` and third column contain `data`.

So, can anyone please tell me how I can do this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is the problem? Looping over the Points? Or creating a file you can import to excel? What did you try? As it stands this question is too broad and shows no research effort.

Comment: As of now I am able to put points on chart. I am assuming that each and every series of chart store the points so by traversing on the series I can get all the points. But I want to know is their any inbuilt function I can use to achieve my goal? If not then someone can provide some code snippet.

Comment: No, but Linq will let you access the points and pull their data out to some structure of your choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the following [solution](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-excel-chart.htm). First you will need to add reference to Microsoft Excel Object Library of COM. See this link on how to [add](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-create-excel.htm). Then next step is pretty simple. You will need to add the code from the above link and replace the data which you fed in Excel with your custom data.

Here is the code shown in the link.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Excel.Application xlApp;
     Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
     Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
     object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

     xlApp = new Excel.Application();
     xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
     xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

     for (int i = 0; i < chart1.Series.Count; i++)
     {
      xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "";
      xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "DateTime";//put your column heading here
      xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Data";// put your column heading here

      for (int j = 0; j < chart1.Series[i].Points.Count; j++)
      {
       xlWorkSheet.Cells[j + 2 , 2] = chart1.Series[i].Points[j].XValue;
       xlWorkSheet.Cells[j + 2 , 3] = chart1.Series[i].Points[j].YValues[0];
      }
     }

     Excel.Range chartRange;

     Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (Excel.ChartObjects)xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
     Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(10, 80, 300, 250);
     Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;

     chartRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("B2", "c5");//update the range here
     chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, misValue);
     chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlColumnClustered;

     xlWorkBook.SaveAs("csharp.net-informations.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
     xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
     xlApp.Quit();

     releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
     releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
     releaseObject(xlApp);

     MessageBox.Show("Excel file created , you can find the file c:\\csharp.net-informations.xls");
 }

 private void releaseObject(object obj)
 {
  try
  {
   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
   obj = null;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
   obj = null;
   MessageBox.Show("Exception Occured while releasing object " + ex.ToString());
   }
   finally
   {
    GC.Collect();
   }
 }
```

Simply replace the cells and data from the code with your custom data and viola when you click on export button it will export it for you.

Comment: 'Viola' LOL. A little more dynamics sure would make it more useful.. Also I always avoid writeing into the system root.

Comment: This actually saved it to the user Documents folder for me